# JOLT - Split array into elements for Nifi Databaserecord

Tags: arrays, json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I am struggeling with some jolt transformation. I need to extract informations from an array, but also need some uppper level informations.
I have bills and some bills have multiple attachments. I want to store this attachments in a Postgress db and for each attachment aplly the bill id...

My input

```
[
  {
    "bill_id": 1,
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "alpha",
        "data": "foo"
      },
      {
        "type": "beta",
        "data": "bar"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "bill_id": 2,
    "entities": []
  }
]
```

My desired output

```
[
  {
    "bill_id": 1,
    "type": "alpha",
    "data": "foo"
  },
  {
    "bill_id": 1,
    "type": "beta",
    "data": "bar"
  }
]
```

I would be very glad, if someone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found an answer, that perfectly matches my needs. A little bit tricky, but it is working fine with two shifts:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "entities": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,bill_id)": "[&3].[&1].bill_id",
            "type": "[&3].[&1].type",
            "data": "[&3].[&1].data"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```